# How to properly index and modify generic partial

Tags: typescript

This is my first generic type function and will appreciate if somebody could assist with my missing understanding of Partials and in general TS behaviour.

What is intended to achieve:
1. Pass object of type `<T>`
2. Modify it and return expected object of type `<U>`

The example below with the live warnings in codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/small-wood-yq14e

P.S: I am open to new ideas of how the whole thing should be actually approached in TS best practices :-)

```
export type ObjectWithStrings = { [index: string]: string }


// some demo data
const CONTAINER_NUTRIENTS_NAMES_ORDER: ObjectWithStrings = {}
const LIPIDS_NUTRIENTS_NAMES_ORDER: ObjectWithStrings = {}
const NUTRIENTS_MODEL_MAP: ObjectWithStrings = {}

function _sortNutrientsModel<T> (nutrientsModel: T) {
  const sortedNutrientsModel: Partial<T> = {}

  for (const sectionName in CONTAINER_NUTRIENTS_NAMES_ORDER) {
    if (CONTAINER_NUTRIENTS_NAMES_ORDER.hasOwnProperty(sectionName)) {
      /* 
      sortedNutrientsModel[sectionName]:
      Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Partial<T>'.
      No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Partial<T>'.ts(7053)

      nutrientsModel[sectionName]:
      Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
      No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.ts(7053) */
      sortedNutrientsModel[sectionName] = nutrientsModel[sectionName]
    }
  }

  for (const sectionName in LIPIDS_NUTRIENTS_NAMES_ORDER) {
    /* 
    Property 'lipids' does not exist on type 'T'.ts(2339) */
    if (LIPIDS_NUTRIENTS_NAMES_ORDER.hasOwnProperty(sectionName) && sortedNutrientsModel.lipids.sections[sectionName]) {
      sortedNutrientsModel.lipids.sections[sectionName] = nutrientsModel.lipids.sections[sectionName]
    }
  }

  return sortedNutrientsModel
}

export function createNutrientsModel<T extends object, U> (nutrients: T) {
  const nutrientsModel: Partial<U> = {}

  for (const nutrientName in nutrients) {
    if (nutrients.hasOwnProperty(nutrientName)) {
      const nutrientLocation = NUTRIENTS_MODEL_MAP[nutrientName]

      if (typeof nutrientLocation === `string`) {
        const nutrientValues = nutrients[nutrientName]

        switch (nutrientLocation.length) {
          case 0: /* Container nutrient section */
            /*
            Type 'Extract<keyof T, string>' cannot be used to index type 'Partial<U>'.ts(2536) */
            if (typeof nutrientsModel[nutrientName] === `undefined`) {
             /*
              Type 'Extract<keyof T, string>' cannot be used to index type 'Partial<U>'.ts(2536) */
              nutrientsModel[nutrientName] = {}
            }

           /*
            Type 'Extract<keyof T, string>' cannot be used to index type 'Partial<U>'.ts(2536) */
            nutrientsModel[nutrientName].values = nutrientValues
            break
          default: /* Nutrient section */
           /*
            Type 'Extract<keyof T, string>' cannot be used to index type 'Partial<U>'.ts(2536) */
            if (nutrientsModel[nutrientLocation] === `undefined`) {
             /*
              Type 'Extract<keyof T, string>' cannot be used to index type 'Partial<U>'.ts(2536) */
              nutrientsModel[nutrientLocation] = {}
            }

           /*
            Type 'Extract<keyof T, string>' cannot be used to index type 'Partial<U>'.ts(2536) */   
            if (typeof nutrientsModel[nutrientLocation].sections === `undefined`) {
              nutrientsModel[nutrientLocation].sections = {}
            }

           /*
            Type 'Extract<keyof T, string>' cannot be used to index type 'Partial<U>'.ts(2536) */ 
            nutrientsModel[nutrientLocation].sections[nutrientName] = {
              values: nutrientValues
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return _sortNutrientsModel(nutrientsModel) as U
}
```

UPDATE with example of **NutrientsType**

```
interface BalanceModelSection {
  DRI: {
    AI: number,
    AMDR: BalanceModelAMDR
    EAR: number,
    RDA: number,
    UL: number,
    unit: string
    [index: string]: string | number | BalanceModelAMDR
  }
}

interface BalanceRecordSectionValues {
  converted: {
    quantity: number
    recommended: number
    unit: string
  }
  quantity: number
  percentage: string
}

interface BalanceRecordSection extends
  BalanceRecordSectionValues,
  BalanceModelSection {}

interface BalanceRecordNutrients {
  [index: string]: BalanceRecordSection | BalanceRecordProgressSection
  energy: BalanceRecordSection
}
```

Comment: ```nutrients: T``` Could you give type for that one?

Comment: @Drag13 thank you for the help. BalanceRecordProgressSection is just a bit different in terms of internal structure but is 90% same as BalanceRecordSection type

Comment: If you're trying to do anything that involves dynamically referencing the type argument `U` given, then what you're asking for is impossible without some serious hackery and a ttypescript custom transformer.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what is the objective? Following point 1 and 2, what to modify from object of type `T` and what is `U` according to `T`?

Comment: Sidenote: you don't need `ObjectWithStrings`, you can use `Record<string, string>`.

Comment: @volna How about updating code example to include those additional interfaces?

Comment: @Nenad thank you for the help with this investigation :-) I've updated https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-pine-sly2d?file=/src/index.ts with the files that contain types and added function calls

Comment: @volna Your mapping code is full of bugs. For example:`Type 'ProductNutrientValues' is missing the following properties from type 'ProductNutrientsModelContainerSection': values, sectionsts(2322)`. So I suggest you rewrite your logic now that you have defined interfaces.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the issue Nenad. Do you mean that it's better to create a separate function for each specific data model output?

Comment: @Nenad I believe I didn't properly explain the intention. I have an object that contains values (product nutrients) my intention is to pass it to the function and split it by categories (assign to sections) and export and nutrients model (the second U type a pass as arg)

Comment: For this reason, product nutrients initially don't have sections since it only contains values :-)

Comment: @volna I understand what you are saying, but the code example is very far from what you actually want to achieve that it's better that you start from scratch now you introduced valid interfaces.

Comment: I'll give it a try thank you, @Nenad :-)